# Why does this Linux kernel page table code wrap a return value in braces?

Tags: linux, kernel

In the following code, can you please explain the braces following the `(pgd_t)` in the `return` statement which is `{ val };`. Is this code casting `val`? What is the return statement doing using the expression `{ val };`?

```
static inline pgd_t native_make_pgd(pgdval_t val)
    {
            return (pgd_t) { val };
    }
```

Comment: There are lots of functions structured like this in http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h

Answer (score 1):

If you look right before the function, you'll see:

```
typedef struct { pgdval_t pgd; } pgd_t;
```

So the code is effectively equivalent to:

```
pgd_t temp = { val };
return temp;
```

The braces are part of the syntax for initializing a structure. The cast syntax allows you to create the structure as part of an expression, rather than when initializing a variable.